# How to create Swagger doc from multiple swagger files

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0

I defined APIs through swagger. For each micro-service, I have a swagger file say micro-service1.yaml.Like that I have around 40 micro-services. Accessing each one is difficult . I want to access all of the through a common URL.How can I achieve the same. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use WebSphere Liberty, since it will aggregate all the APIs running in it and show you them in a single Swagger UI.

However, for 40 micro-services the recommended topology would be to separate them into different WebSphere Collective members (Java w/ Liberty or Node w/ Loopback), where either of them can be inside a Docker container), so you could see all the APIs from the aggregated Collective Controller Swagger UI.

More info in this [blog](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/blog/2017/03/15/new-enhancements-libertys-openapi-support/).